# Why is $a_{n} < \sum_{r=0}^{n} \frac{1}{r!}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, intuition

Guys I have done a lot of thinking but I cannot see why this is true. Book says In (2.8), each of the factors

$ 1-(\frac{i}{n})$

is less than 1, and so from (2.6) we deduce that

$a_{n} < \sum_{r=0}^{n} \frac{1}{r!}$.

$a_{n}=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}\frac{1}{n^{r}}$ (2.6)

$\binom{n}{r}\frac{1}{n^r}=\frac{n(n-1)...(n-r+1)}{r!n^r}=\frac{1}{r!}(1-\frac{1}{n})(1-\frac{2}{n})...(1-\frac{r-1}{n})$ (2.8)

I have tried many methods but I cannot see why this is true. I still think

$a_{n} > \sum_{r=0}^{n}\frac{1}{r!}$

and

$(1-\frac{1}{n})(1-\frac{2}{n})...(1-\frac{r-1}{n})$

makes it increase. 
I hope I will get rigorous proof about it. 
Please Help me deduce it since I have very little time left. 
Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: What is $a_n$ ? Which book are you referring to ? Please provide more reference.

Comment: Springer undergraduate real analysis.

Comment: Can you provide us with a link or photo of the page you are referring to ?

Comment: Pg no.40. Chapter Sequence and series.

Comment: It is proof of lim_n->infinity(1+1/n)^n using binomial.

Answer (score 1):

It’s actually quite clear

$$\binom{n}{r}\frac{1}{n^r}=\frac{n(n-1)...(n-r+1)}{r!n^r}=\frac{1}{r!}\underbrace{(1-\frac{1}{n})}_{<1}\underbrace{(1-\frac{2}{n})}_{<1}\cdots\underbrace{(1-\frac{r-1}{n})}_{<1}<\frac{1}{r!}$$
Now sum them up to get $a_n$.

Comment: Man , thanks I had a vague thought now it is clear. (Palm face)

Comment: Glad to be of help. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is because each term of $a_n$ satisfies
$$\binom nr \frac 1{n^r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}\frac1{n^r}=\frac 1{r!}\frac{n(n-1)\dotsm(n-r+1)}{n^r}<\frac1{r!}\frac{n^r}{n^r}=\frac1{r!}.$$

Comment: I think this will be kinda hard to understand because you now have to prove $$n(n−1)⋯(n−r+1)<n^{r}$$ Though thanks for an alternative explanation.

Comment: That's pretty obvious: each factor except the first is less than $n$, and there are $r$ factors in all.

Comment: (I guess today I should stop thinking mathematics since I am making a lot of Funny mistakes.) Thanks for help mate!

Comment: Not seing patently obvious things happens to all of us. It also depends  in which direction our mind is looking!

Comment: Hey, but how long did it take you to find this obvious pattern?

Comment: It was longer to type than to find it :)